Complex contour integral $\int\limits_{\partial \Omega}e^{\frac{x}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})}dz$
I' ve got an integral: $$\int\limits_{\partial \Omega}e^{\frac{x}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})}dz,$$
where $|z|<1$
I've tried to use Residue theorem, but i don't think that it is a good idea, because of the function Re(z) inside the integral.
So, I have replaced the variable: $z = e^{i \phi}$ and got:
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i\phi + cos^2(\phi)}d\phi$$
But i don't know what to do next

Is $x$ a constant or is it the real part of $z$ or something else entirely?

We have  $$e^{i\phi+\cos^2(\phi)}=e^{i\phi}e^{\cos^2(\phi)}=\cos(\phi)e^{\cos^2(\phi)}+i\sin(\phi)e^{\cos^2(\phi)}$$
Now, $f(\phi)=\cos(\phi)e^{\cos^2(\phi)}$ is even, so its integral on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is double its integral on $[0,\pi]$. But cosine is symmetric respect to $\pi/2$, so the integral on $[0,\pi]$, and thus on $[-\pi,\pi]$, is $0$.
As for $g(\phi)=i\sin(\phi)e^{\cos^2(\phi)}$, this function is odd and so its integral on a symmetric interval as $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $0$.
Consequently, $$\int\limits_{\partial \Omega}e^{\frac{x}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})}dz=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i\phi + cos^2(\phi)}d\phi=0$$

thank you, didn’t notice such simple fact….
